# why "myStat" are not matched

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Goal:
    I'm going to translate a pseudocode(which mixed a personal defined code and the standard C) to the standard C.Just translate the personal defined code and copy the part of standard C(including the blanks/tabs).

```
pseudocode:
    int main()
    {
        int a = 0;
        -Export()    //personal defined code        
        return 0;
    }

target file:
    int main()
    {
        int a = 0;
        MyExport();   //translated
        return 0;
    }

g4 file:
    prog:   myStat*   |
            cppStat*    ;

    myStat : EXPORTFUNC;

    cppStat : OtherLine ;

    EXPORTFUNC    : [\t ]*'-Export()\r\n';

    NL : '\r'?'\n'

    OtherLine : OTHER* (NL|EOF);

    fragment OTHER :~[\r\n]+ ;
```

question:
    the "-Export()" in pseudocode can't be matched by parse rule "myStat".

```
(prog (cppStat int main()\r\n)    
      (cppStat {\r\n)    
      (cppStat \tint a= 0;\r\n)     
      -Export\r\n                    //doesn't match "myStat"   
      (cppStat \taaaaa\r\n)    
      (cppStat }\r\n) \r\n)
```

what should I  do to correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Export()` line in the source can be matched by both the `myStat` and `cppStat` rules. Since the longest rule match wins and `cppStat` includes the leading whitespace, `myStat` loses.

As a general principle, `skip` anything that is not syntactically significant to the parsing.

Comment: I change the  ‘myStat‘ to '[\t ]*'-Export()\r\n'' but it's still out of work.By the way,I need to keep the blanks(tabs).